# MySQL - Compare total this week against same week last year

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I get a sum of sales totals for the current week against the same week last year?

There are two possible scenarios related to how the dates are stored, as below:

**Scenario 1**

```
**Sales**

Date          Sales    
-----------------------   
2012-08-10    11040.00
2012-08-09    11500.00
2012-08-08    14060.00
2012-08-07    93000.00
2012-08-06    11200.00
...
2011-08-10    11040.00
2011-08-09    11500.00
2011-08-08    14060.00
2011-08-07    93000.00
2011-08-06    11200.00
```

**Scenario 2**

```
**Sales**

year         month       day         Sales
---------------------------------------------       
2012         08          10          11040.00
2012         08          09          11500.00
2012         08          08          14060.00
2012         08          07          23000.00
2012         08          06          11200.00
...
2011         08          10          13040.00
2011         08          09          11500.00
2011         08          08          12060.00
2011         08          07          33000.00
2011         08          06          11250.00
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week + `GROUP BY` + `SUM`

Comment: @Dean Grell: too bored to write a complete query, and as a small set of tips it would be better to left it as a comment :-)

Comment: Please define *same week last year*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first scenario, join against the same table on the `WEEKOFYEAR()` and one added to last year's `YEAR()`:

```
SELECT
  YEARWEEK(thisyear.Date) AS `YearWeek`
  SUM(lastyear.Sales) AS LastYearSales
  SUM(thisyear.Sales) AS ThisYearSales
FROM
  Sales thisyear
  LEFT JOIN Sales lastyear ON
      WEEKOFYEAR(thisyear.Date) = WEEKOFYEAR(lastyear.Date) 
      AND YEAR(thisyear.Date) = (YEAR(lastyear.Date) + 1)
GROUP BY `YearWeek`
```

The second scenario requires building a date out of the 3 separate values. I *think* this will work:

```
SELECT
  YEARWEEK(CONCAT_WS('-', thisyear.year, thisyear.month, thisyear.day)) AS `YearWeek`,
  SUM(lastyear.Sales) AS LastYearSales,
  SUM(thisyear.Sales) AS ThisYearSales
FROM
  Sales thisyear
  LEFT JOIN Sales lastyear ON
    WEEKOFYEAR(CONCAT_WS('-', thisyear.year, thisyear.month, thisyear.day)) = WEEKOFYEAR(CONCAT_WS('-', lastyear.year + 1, lastyear.month, lastyear.day))
GROUP BY `YearWeek`
```

Comment: This will return NULLs for 53rd week but that may well be within requirements. One of our clients had continually been having issues with how we calculated last year weeks until we abandoned week numbers and introduced this simple formula: `last_year.week_start = this_year.week_start - 364 days`.